# How to find and delete a particular file every directory using linux command

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal

I'm using ubuntu 15.10. I have "backup_old.zip" file in more than 100 directories. How can I remove all "backup_old.zip" file in single linux shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shell command was worked for me.

```
$ find . -name backup_old.zip -type f -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rm](https://linuxconfig.org/rm-1-manual-page) command to remove files.

```
rm -f */backup_old.zip
```